# How do I add my whole project on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub account. I fixed up everything, so I'm ready for uploads.

GitHub's [help on creating a repo](http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/) covers uploading a single README file, but I want to upload the entire project. How I can do it step by step?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to use `git`? You're supposed to have your own repo locally that you can "push" to github once you have set up everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new repository here https://github.com/repositories/new

git clone to local folder, add files of project

and then "git add ." "git commit" & "git push"

Maybe you must add ssh key into github panel(I dont remeber)

Comment: You can't clone an empty repo.

Comment: You have to write git remote add origin "url_to_repo" then you have a connection to your  repo, after that you push your project there...

Answer (score 1):

The "single README" is just an example. Of course you can add, commit and push as much files as you like. The README-file is special to github, because its shown at the bottom of the repositories page (side note: works in subdirectories too). Thats the only reason, why they only mention this one.

```
git add README
git add otherFile
git add aDirectory
```

It really doesn't make any difference for github *when* you commit and push specific files to github. However, I'm used to add only the most general files (README and some license files) to the initial commit. Its just a matter of your personal preference.